# Dynamically Change contents in a fragment(To reduce the number of fragments)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am developing a quizzing application, which has an activity and as many as 15 fragments where each fragment represents a "question page" containing a question and its options. I'm thinking of another design, where there is only a single fragment for "question page" and whose contents (i.e the question and its options) gets dynamically replaced by the next question and its options. Is this possible? If it is, please tell me how.

Comment: 15 Fragments? Are they all serving different purposes?

Comment: @Egor: I am making a quiz application  where each fragment represents a question. So they are serving different purposes, I guess

Comment: Is it possible for you to have a single Fragment that can show any question and can be reused for all questions? That would simplify your app's design by a lot.

Comment: @Egor: That sounds like a great idea. Can you please tell me how to make a single fragment for all the questions?

Comment: @TonyMathew I didnt get exactly but you can create **newInstance** in your fragment and pass necessary data for each fragment.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a Separate interface.

```
public interface QuestionOne 
{ 
   void QuestionOneA(int score);
}
```

Every fragment have a Member variables QuestionOne. And your Activity only implements QuestionOne.

Comment: The thing is, I'm new to Android. It would be really helpful if you could explain how to me to create a seperate interface and for every member to have a member variable of Questionone